# Can't see GRect move

Tags: java

I want to create an event such that on a mouse event, there is a test for true/false, and in the case of false, a simple animation occurs, but I only see the result of the animation, not the animation itself.

I've defined "miss", "dx" and "dy" as instance variables.

```
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    swingSword();
    determineHit();
    if (determineHit()){
        GRect test = new GRect(testX, testY, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
        test.setFilled(true);
        test.setFillColor(Color.GREEN);
        add(test);
        testX += 30;
    }
    else {
        GRect test = new GRect(testX, testY, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
        test.setFilled(true);
        test.setFillColor(Color.RED);
        add(test);
        testX += 30;

        miss = new GRect(200, 200, BRICK_WIDTH, BRICK_HEIGHT);
        miss.setFilled(true);
        miss.setFillColor(Color.RED);
        add(miss);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            miss.move(dx, dy);
            pause(200);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ah acm, what I had to learn before unlearning it to learn java.

Comment: What's wrong with this code?

Comment: I don't see the GRect "miss" move across the screen, the GRect just appears at the end of the total delay count.

Answer (score 1):

You are blocking the event dispatch thread.

The thread that executes the `mousePressed` method is the same that is resposible for *repainting*. So while this thread is processing the `for`-loop (and waiting in the `pause` method) he has no chance to actually repaint the screen.

Depending on the surrounding infrastructure, you could solve this either with an own thread, or with a swing timer. That means that you could replace your `for`-loop with code that *roughly* looks like this:

```
final Timer timer = new Timer(200, null);
timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    int counter = 0;
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
         miss.move(dx, dy);
         counter++;
         if (counter >= 10)
         {
             timer.stop();
         }
    }
});
timer.start();
```